# NextJS where defines tilde '~' symbol in import path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I read code in an app with NextJS. It imports component like `import Head from '~/components/layout/head'`

The project structure:

```
-app
---components
---pages
---public
```

I wonder where defines `~` as root dir in nextJS.

Where can I find the config of this?
Tried uncover the webpack config inside next package, but didn't find.

Comment: is this a Typescript project?

Comment: @felixmosh yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this is because the babel plugin `babel-plugin-root-import`, since the project uses this plugin in babel config.

More about this plugin can check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-root-import).

Answer (score 7):

With Typescript's `paths` feature you can specify a module mapping.

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

This will allow you to import using

```js
import x from '~/components/layout/head';
```

that will be mapped to `src/components/layout/head`.

If your are using webpack, you will need to use [`tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin).

Comment: Thx for telling! Based on your answer, I find this root path define is done by `babel-plugin-root-import`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases).

You can set the module mapping without extra libs.

In your file structure, try this example.

```
// tsconfig.json 

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~*": ["./*]
    }
  }
}
```

Then go to your files:

```
import { xxx } from '~/components';

// or

import xxx from '~/components/xxx';
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer, thanks! +1