# What does "~" (tilde) mean in the import ... from "~/"

Tags: javascript, vite, ecma

I just spotted "~/" in some of js imports

```js
import { Foo, Bar, Baz } from "~/types/schema"
```

This is mildly confusing because "~" usually meant the `$HOME` directory. And for the life of me - I can't google the answer.

The only answer I found was this [What is the ~ (tilde) doing in this javascript import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113870/what-is-the-tilde-doing-in-this-javascript-import)
dealing with `import {IDispatch} from '~react-redux~redux';` which uses the tilde sign, but not as int the path `~something` instead of `~/something`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the ~ (tilde) doing in this javascript import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113870/what-is-the-tilde-doing-in-this-javascript-import)

Comment: Thanks for checking, but no, it doesn't. I've seen this answer before. Added a paragraph explaining how it is different.

Comment: No problem! [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58522502/3789527) might be relevant too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be part of the frontend tooling that one is using, like Webpack or Vite. For example:

1. If you're using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) `~` might be resolving to `node_modules`. Check your config for [`resolvealias` feature](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias). But beware, that it seems it might come from other dependencies. See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226632/299774 and also the discussion in the comments.
2. If you're using [vite](https://vite-ruby.netlify.app/): it resolves `~` to `sourceCodeDir`. So check your config for `sourceCodeDir` value. See https://vite-ruby.netlify.app/guide/development.html#import-aliases-%F0%9F%91%89 and https://vite-ruby.netlify.app/config/#sourcecodedir
3. Also Typescript has `paths` feature to specify module mappings. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58522502/3789527

Comment: Your answer suggests that simply using Webpack or Vite at all would *automatically* resolve `~` to some directory in your project, but that's not correct.

The `~` is resolved by an explicit configuration (Webpack's `resolve.alias` or Vite's `resolve.alias`). The alias is **not** "predefined" by Webpack like the answer you linked to would indicate. If `~` resolves correctly without your own config, then likely something else in your tech stack (e.g., Vite Ruby, as you've cited in your answer) is configuring the alias.

Comment: [demo - Webpack does not preconfigure path alias](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-webpack-js-org-9hn17z?file=src%2Ftypes%2Fschema.js,src%2Findex.js%3AL2-L2,package.json&terminal=build,start)

Comment: [demo - Vite does not preconfigure path alias](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-un8kwi?file=src%2Ftypes%2Fschema.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&terminal=dev)

Comment: @tony19 thank you for the review, you are right! I updated the answer - please let me know if it's clearer now.

Comment: @tony19 @Greg Is it `sourceCodeDir` or is it `resolve.alias`??

Comment: @AlxVallejo It depends on the tool you're using. webpack has one, vite has another. Is the answer not clear on that?